# Spinner RecyclerView

Tags: android, spinner, android-recyclerview

This is Priyatham Suresh, I am new to android.

I am using spinner with RecyclerView. I have row which contains textView and spinner. I want to get the row position of a RecyclerView, when i select the spinner item.

I have used ListView intitially and used onItemSelected which is giving spinner item positon but unable to get row position.

here is my row table_settings_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Table Number"
        android:id="@+id/tableNo_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff7c40"
        android:editable="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/users_spinner"
            android:entries="@array/sample_members"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Priyatham just go through this [link](http://androhub.com/android-recyclerview/).

Comment: Please post the code of your ViewHolder implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just, set tag(position) to spinner on OnBindView. Now, when you select spinner, you can get tag of that spinner, which is position you want.